# Css border/line style without effecting the side borders

Tags: css

Hi I'm trying to create a line similar to this:

[image]

My page is composed of sections which alternate in colour as the user scrolls down.  However it's a little bland.  I am just wondering how to create that border line effect between sections like in the picture?

I know how to do border shadows etc...but when I do it..it affects all sides of the box.  I only want the top and bottom bits of the section to be effected...not the sides.

I've also tried using mox box shadows:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

but they aren't visible between sections.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably need to use **inset** box-shadows. [**See this**](http://makandracards.com/makandra/12019-css-emulate-borders-with-inset-box-shadows)

Comment: inset would just add the shadow to the inside

Comment: Thanks but there doesn't seem to be any effect when I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add minus px to the shadow to bring it back in.

```css
div {width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 18px 15px -18px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but there doesn't seem to be any effect when I use them?

Comment: if you run the snippet you can see it works. The minus position should equal the vertical length.

Comment: Your snippet definitely works...but on my page nothing happens.

Comment: Then you'll need to look at your page in firebug to debug what's blocking it from happening.

Comment: Do I need to do separate divs?

My page is composed of sections

I.e  <section1>
Content
    </section1>

 <section2>
Content
    </section2>

I would like inset box shadows separating the content.

Comment: no, just apply the css to the `section {}`  <section1> isn't a tag by the way!

Comment: Thanks it works.  Is there a way to remove the shadows at the sides?  I only want the top and bottom.